# How to play Soma.FM on Google Chrome with Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: google-chrome

How would I make my Chrome work in order to reproduce Soma.FM?

When I visit: http://somafm.com/play/lush instead of starting playing on Chrome, I get a download of a pls file, which when trying to open it with Rythmbox it doesn't do anything.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there is a Chrome plugin that will support streaming audio. I use media players like iTunes and Rythmbox instead.

Add a new Internet Radio Station in Rythmbox (Control-I) using the following address: `http://somafm.com/lush.pls` or visit http://somafm.com/lush/directstreamlinks.html for other streaming source links. I've found that using the links rather than downloaded .pls files is better when dealing with soma.fm streams.